# Python 3 Tkinter Borderless fullscreen application

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, fullscreen, window-managers

I have been having a problem whilst creating a Python 3 tkinter application. I am currently developing using a Mac OSX system, but I normally use a Windows OS system.

I would like the application to occupy the entire screen without the Window Manager's titlebar and frame being around the application, often referred to a Fullscreen Borderless Window in gaming.

I have tried using `root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)` with `root.overrideredirect(True)` and `root.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)`. However the inclusion of the `root.overrideredirect(True)` line doesn't allow it to go proper fullscreen; it still shows the Mac Dock and Taskbar, and it also breaks my keystroke bindings in the application. Without the `root.overrideredirect(True)` line, the application does go into full screen mode (hiding the dock and the task bar), but the window does not fill the entire screen; it leaves a gap at the bottom, and it also retains the window manager's title bar and frame/border.

Here is an example of my code:

```
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.parent = parent

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.parent.title("Fullscreen Application")

        self.pack(fill="both", expand=True, side="top")

        self.parent.wm_state("zoomed")

        self.parent.bind("<F11>", self.fullscreen_toggle)
        self.parent.bind("<Escape>", self.fullscreen_cancel)

        self.fullscreen_toggle()

        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="Fullscreen", font=("default",120), fg="black")
        self.label.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

    def fullscreen_toggle(self, event="none"):

        self.parent.focus_set()
        self.parent.overrideredirect(True)

        self.parent.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
        self.parent.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)

    def fullscreen_cancel(self, event="none"):

        self.parent.overrideredirect(False)
        self.parent.attributes("-fullscreen", False)
        self.parent.wm_attributes("-topmost", 0)

        self.centerWindow()

    def centerWindow(self):

        sw = self.parent.winfo_screenwidth()
        sh = self.parent.winfo_screenheight()

        w = sw*0.7
        h = sh*0.7

        x = (sw-w)/2
        y = (sh-h)/2

        self.parent.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (w, h, x, y))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    App(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

I hope that someone is able to help! Thank you!

**EDIT:** I have just tested this on my Windows computer. Without the `self.parent.overrideredirect(True)`, it creates the app and works perfectly as desired (fullscreen without window manager border or title bar). This must just be an OSX problem.

Comment: Have you tried changing the root geometry and add an extra 5 or something to the width and/or height?

Comment: I have, it sadly didn't work. Thanks for the suggestion anyway. :)

Comment: Please select an answer, or comment on the answer that didn't satisfy the required fix.

Answer (score 1):

To fix your OS-X Problem i will provide a solution that fixes a similar problem for me. (Had some Issues using fullscreen in between Linux and Windows)

You wanted to get rid of the Window Managers Bar? Take a look at [the docs](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.attributes-method) it states an option that removes the window managers items by using `-toolwindow` option.

Concerning the size of your Application here is what helped me using linux - a "manual zoom":

```
class MyClass(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.overrideredirect(True) # depending on your needs
        self.attributes("-toolwindow", 1) # this line removes the window managers bar

        try:                                   # Automatic zoom if possible
            self.wm_state("zoomed")
            print("Using automatic zoom")
        except tk.TclError:                    # Manual zoom
            # Bad Argument Error is a TclError
            print("Using manual zoom")

            # get the screen dimensions
            width = self.winfo_screenwidth()
            height = self.winfo_screenheight()

            # build a geometry string. 
            # form: width x height + x_offset + y_offset
            geom_string = "%dx%d+0+0" % (width, height)
            self.wm_geometry(geom_string)
```

Please note that I am not using an unconfigured tk.Tk() - Instance here - my class **is** the tk.Tk() - Instance. So I do not need to overwrite the parent but only "myself" speaking of the POV of the class.

Comment: Tool windows have a titlebar without an icon, minimize, and maximize button. It has a title and a close button. This is not a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import Tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.parent = parent

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.parent.title("Fullscreen Application")

        self.pack(fill="both", expand=True, side="top")

        self.parent.wm_state("zoomed")

        self.parent.bind("<F11>", self.fullscreen_toggle)
        self.parent.bind("<Escape>", self.fullscreen_cancel)

        self.fullscreen_toggle()

        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="Fullscreen", font=("default",120), fg="black")
        self.label.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

    def fullscreen_toggle(self, event="none"):

        self.parent.focus_set()
        self.parent.overrideredirect(True)
        self.parent.overrideredirect(False) #added for a toggle effect, not fully sure why it's like this on Mac OS
        self.parent.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
        self.parent.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)

    def fullscreen_cancel(self, event="none"):

        self.parent.overrideredirect(False)
        self.parent.attributes("-fullscreen", False)
        self.parent.wm_attributes("-topmost", 0)

        self.centerWindow()

    def centerWindow(self):

        sw = self.parent.winfo_screenwidth()
        sh = self.parent.winfo_screenheight()

        w = sw*0.7
        h = sh*0.7

        x = (sw-w)/2
        y = (sh-h)/2

        self.parent.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (w, h, x, y))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    App(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you want to be more specifc [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44328765/how-do-i-display-a-tkinter-application-in-fullscreen-on-macos)