# How do I display a tkinter application in fullscreen on macOS?

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, tkinter, fullscreen

I am just learning python, and I am trying to make a window go full screen, which I have achieved, but I am now wanting to get rid of the title bar across the top. It currently looks like the image below, but I want it to also go over the Mac top toolbar at top (like a splash screen).

[image]

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
root.attributes('-topmost', True)
root.overrideredirect(True)



def quitApp():
    # mlabel = Label (root, text = 'Close').pack()
    root.destroy()

# placing the button on my window
button = Button(text = 'QUIT', command = quitApp).pack()
```

Comment: There is [overrideredirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38162932/what-does-overrideredirect-do) method that works with windows but not sure how/if it works on mac.

Comment: I tried that but didnt do anything (maybe I done wrong)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe what you want to do is use

`root.wm_attributes('-fullscreen','true')`

Try this instead. It should do the trick.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

root.wm_attributes('-fullscreen','true')

def quitApp():
    root.destroy()

button = Button(text = 'QUIT', command = quitApp).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

If this does not work because of the MacOS then take a look at this [link](http://wiki.tcl.tk/13428) This useful page has sever examples of how to manage mack windows in tkinter. And I believe what you may need to get borderless fullscreen.

This bit of code might be what you need:

```
root.tk.call("::tk::unsupported::MacWindowStyle", "style", root._w, "plain", "none")
```

Note: If you do use this option then you will need to remove `root.wm_attributes('-fullscreen','true')` from your code or just comment it out.

Update:

There is also another bit of code for tkinter 8.5+.

If you are using python with tkinter 8.5 or newer:

```
root.wm_attributes('-fullscreen', 1)
```

Comment: Hi, that gets rid of the Mac tool bar (if thats what its called), but still shows the app title bar